# I want a shortcut in Excel to cells I have Hyperlinked

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I've built a Series of Cells which wnen concateneted = HyperLink to a remote server. Excel Wk Sheet 2010  (File name changes Daily with date function or Date User inputs) 
On the same Sheet I want to built a Shortcut to the Hyperlinked text mentinoned above. 
Heres WHat I have IN Cell AA14  '=Hyperlink(AC14&AD14) Works like a champ - but has a hugh long address. I want to shorten that to short referance "Today's EOD:"

I want to have a shortcut in Cell  I14 With a Label TODAYS REPORT & link to Cell AA14. 
I Cannot get it to link and drive to the end location on a shared Drive. 
In I14 I labeled TODAY,  Tried To Referance AA14 & Creat a hyperlink get error Cannot open specified FIle - I'm out of soap - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a little bit of VBA. Note that this assumes there are no other hyperlinks in the workbook.

1. Open the VBA IDE with Alt-F11.
2. Add a module by clicking on Insert, Module
3. Copy and paste the code below into the module
4. Add a shape to cell I14.
5. Right click on the shape and edit the text with some meaningful name, e.g., To Server
6. Right click on the shape and Assign Macro `followMe` to the shape.

You will have to save the file as a macro-enabled workbook (*.xlsm).  To avoid security warnings add the folder where the file is saved to Trusted Locations (File, Options, Trust Center, Trust Center Settings, Trusted Locations).

#### Code

```
Sub followMe()
Range("N2").Hyperlinks(1).Follow
End Sub
```